# Azure Logic Apps: How do I execute a join query

Tags: azure-sql-database, cloud, computer-science, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to run a query which joins 2 tables from an Azure SQL Database. When I run the query in SQL editor I get the result I need.

However In order to allow users on my website to filter the data I am displaying from this database I am using an Azure Logic App with the query being unsuccessful giving me the following error "BadRequest. Http request failed: the content was not a valid JSON. Error while parsing JSON: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path '', line 0, position 0."

The query is

```
"select *
from [dbo].[Players] e
inner join [dbo].[Player_Stats] p
on e.playerID = p.playerID
order by Assists DESC"
```

I have no idea why this would be the case, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a JSON deserialization error, make sure the result is cleared of any special characters, quotes or escape characters before passing it on the SQL activity.

Further checkout MS docs for SQL connector [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/) and for functions for escape characters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference).

Comment: Thank you, I have given these links a read but the issue still remains. I have altered the query to make things easier until I can get it working. Any other query i run in the workflow runs ok, any query with the keyword JOIN seems to throw this error.                                          
 SELECT *
 FROM [dbo].[Players] e
JOIN Player_Stats p ON p.PlayerID = e.PlayerID